# Custom animation while transitioning between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I want to create transition between view controllers like this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qatwqaq2mowocsg/Transitions%20Controller.gif?dl=0

I 've used the following code to create transition but cannot achieve following results.

```
self.settings = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"];
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];

transition.duration = 0.4;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;


[[self navigationController].view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.settings animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
self.settings = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:
 UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                       forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.settings animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: this code snippet perform only UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animation, the curve line (UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut) shows no effect in animation.

Answer (score 0):

Start from iOS7 you can custom the transition effect of system method pushViewController and presentViewController. For example if you need to custom the push effect there is a method in `UINavigationControllerDelegate` named

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> _Nullable)navigationController:(UINavigationController * _Nonnull)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController * _Nonnull)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController * _Nonnull)toVC
```

add the custom animation to fromVC's view and show the toVC's view in proper time

Comment: I used this method and pushed a new object on stack using above code. but the only effect i observed was "fromVC was flipped a bit but toVC slided horizontally."

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a direct implementable chunk of code that represents `THE ANSWER`, this blog should get you through the steps to create your own custom transitions: http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/

Comment: thanks for sharing this blog. I 've googled too much on customizing segue. But my problem is still there, stuck in achieving following requirement.

Comment: what do you mean "following requirement"? do you mean you're stuck on how to actually achieve the gif you posted? is it a matter of needing to figure out how to break down the animation into what you need to do to accomplish it or do you have some kind of error?

Comment: Yeah i 'm stuck on actually achieving the gif.